# why is java array initialization not allowed in a separate line

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, constants

The following line of code compiles. Java allows this shortcut.

```
int[] az = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

But the following does not compile, why?

```
int[] ay;
ay = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: Because the second line is an assignment.  Assignment is not the same as initialisation.  But note that `int[] az = {1,2,3,4,5};` is just syntax sugar for `int[] az = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};`.

Comment: Why, I don't know, but you can't use the short cut form on a separate line, you need to use `ay = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};`

Comment: It *is* allowed in a separate line. It isn't allowed in a separate *statement.*